# After uninstalling mysql, previous settings return back in windows

Tags: windows-10, mysql

I am using MySQL Community Server 5.6 in a Windows 10 (x64) machine. I would like to reinstall MySQL and end up with clean installation (no databases, etc.).  Every time I reinstall it, the previous database and settings come back. How can I remove everything when I uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply solve your problem by following these steps:

**1.** At fist, go to *`Programs and Features`* in Windows and uninstall MySQL using the built-in uninstaller

**2.** Go to `C:\Program Files` directory and delete folder named `MySQL`

**3.** Again go to `C:\Program Files (x86)` directory and delete folder named `MySQL`

**4.** Now go to `C:\ProgramData` directory and delete folder named `MySQL`

**5.** Go to `%appdata%` directory and delete folder named `MySQL`

**6.** Finally, Reinstall MySQL

Hope this helps.